# How can I convert my date "Wed Jan 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) " to JAN 01,2020 using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb, express

Currently I am getting my date from data base in the format of Wed Jan 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) but I want the date in JAN O1,2020 format and I don't want to use mon=ment.js for this. any other ways to achieve this?

Comment: You can try `new Date().toLocaleDateString()`. There are many examples here https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_tolocalestring_date_all

Comment: i ALREADY TRIED THAT WAY NOT WORKING.

Comment: var d = document.getElementsByClassName("date")[0];
console.log(d);
var str = $.datepicker.formatDate('M dd, yy', d);
$('#findate').innerHTML(str);

Comment: sri laskshmi I added my answer using `toLocaleDateString()`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution without moment.js

```js
var n = new Date("Wed Jan 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)");
var options = {
  month: "short",
  day: "numeric",    
  year: "numeric",
  timeZone: 'IST'
}
document.write(n.toLocaleString("en-EN", options));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use moment.js

```
import * as moment from 'moment';

moment('your_date_variable').format('DD/MM/YYYY');
```